# Access URLs of currently pending requests in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I'd like to view the URLs of the pending requests within my app. The [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) state the `$http.pendingRequests` property returns an 'array of config objects for currently pending requests.' In most other cases the `config` object contains a `url` property. All I'm seeing is an array of empty `objects`, with the length of the array matching the number of pending requests.

Is there a way to access the URLs of the currently pending requests in Angular?

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $rootScope, $injector) {
  return {
      request: function(config) {
        var $http = $http || $injector.get('$http');
        console.log($http.pendingRequests);
        return config;
      },
      response: function(response) {
        var $http = $http || $injector.get('$http');
        console.log($http.pendingRequests);
        return response;
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at using [http interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)? Using them would be more work than using the `pendingRequests` array, but it might help. On second thought, you may have the same underlying problem and get empty config objects from that too...

Comment: When do you access the pendingRequest? Are you sure you access them while the request is still running? I always get a list of `config` objects...

Comment: I'm accessing `pendingRequests` within an `$httpProvider.interceptor`. I've updated the question with some code.